# Unable to compile .asm file

Tags: assembly, nasm

I try to compile file with NASM code in Linux terminal using this comand:

```
$ nasm -f elf /path/to/file.asm
```

I have an error. For first I thing that problem in file, I change the format to .asm but it don't help.
Then I change code and past program from wikipedia but still don't work. 
This is error:

```
nasm: fatal: unable to open output file /home/path/to/file.o'`
```

and this is code:

```
section .text
org 0x100
    mov ah, 0x9
    mov dx, hello
    int 0x21

    mov ax, 0x4c00
    int 0x21

section .data
hello:  db 'Hello, world!', 13, 10, '$'
```

Comment: Would help if you told us what the error is, and maybe post your code?

Comment: Is your home directory on some sort of shared device? Windows mount point?

Comment: Even if you could assemble this it won't run on Linux/Ubuntu as a program because this code is designed to be run under MS-DOS. Only way to compile this is with nasm -f bin and then you have to run at an MS-DOS COM program it in an emulator running dos; DOSBox, or dosemu, or other virtual machine/emulation software)

Comment: My best guess is that you don't have proper write access to the folder/file

Comment: I have windows but I install Linux in separata part of disk

Comment: in settings of file stay parameter writing and reading

Comment: If this is a remote mount that goes across to a windows file system then the issue may be the mask in /etc/fstab

Comment: And why i codn't work with this code on Linux,i read that nasm must work in UNIX-like systems

Comment: no,file in Ubuntu's part of disc

Comment: Wherever you got this code from was targeting DOS/MS-DOS. You can compile it on Linux (assuming you fix your permission problems) but you need other software to actually run it. If this is a permission issue you might want to see what happens if you do `sudo nasm -f elf /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/file.asm`

Comment: Try `echo foo > test_output` in the directory you're working in.  If that doesn't work, it's nothing to do with NASM and everything to do with file permissions.  (or `echo foo >  /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/test.txt`).

Comment: Nothing happened,but error was not returned too

Comment: the `echo` will create new file "test_output" and "test.txt" (actually `echo` is just display string to output, but the `> ...` part will redirect standard output to file) ... if you can find those files, and they contain the "foo" text, then write/create file permissions look ok.

Comment: I not can find "test_output" and "test.txt" but i home directory created file "programs_for_trying" and it file contain text 'foo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is not assembler issue, but also sure it helps.
Perhaps, your user is named `staslend`.
If `programs_for_trying`is a file, 
`ls -lha /home/staslend/programs_for_trying` returns 
`drwxrwxr--` in rights.

```
mv /home/staslend/programs_for_trying /home/staslend/tempfile
mkdir /home/staslend/programs_for_trying
cat tempfile
```

You see contents of your file. I think that you have sources in this file. If that is true, do next:

```
mv /home/staslend/tempfile /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/file.asm
```

Make you owner of you directory and its content:

```
$ sudo chown -R staslend /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/
```

Make you and your group able to read, rename and write content to it:

```
$ chmod -R ug+rwx /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/
```

Make everyone able to read content:

```
$ chmod -R a+r /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/
```

Comment: I make all what you tell, but without / on end, terminal say that is not catalog

Comment: But with comand $ nasm -f elf /home/staslend/programs_for_trying/file.asm happened nothing,still error.

Comment: `ls -la /home/staslend/programs_for_trying` shows what? "not catalog" sounds like you have there some file named `programs_for_trying` instead of directory.

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень, maybe you used cyrillic character for letter 'o', e.g. "prоgrams_for_trying", or "programs_fоr_trying", or "prоgrams_fоr_trying"?

Comment: ls -la /home/staslend/programs_for_trying show: -rwxrwxr-- 1 staslend staslend 4 Янв  9 11:08 /home/staslend/programs_for_trying

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень This is not a directory, it is a file, because  there is no "d" in rights. Rights for directories looks like `drwxrwxr--`

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень Edited the answer

Comment: But how can it be not derectory,i create it and put file ''file'' thete.I don't understand

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень Looks like you mistyped your command to move, see edited answer

Comment: Sorry,I got you off the right track. I try to make like  Ped7g sayed early. So i create file with name 'prоgrams_for_trying' . So comand ls -la /home/staslend/programs_for_trying see not directory but file

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень, I understand. I include instructions to get rid of it in my answer.

Comment: OK, I must make all in order. First comand still return -rwxrwxr--. After second I have somethig like this:                                                              mv: after '/ home / staslend / programs_for_trying', the operand specifying the target file

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень, if you not mistyped command i wrote, it is very strange. Try to `rm -rf /home/staslend/programs_for_trying` at all.

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень, is file still present in directory?

Comment: @ЧерныйКамень, maybe something wrong with our hard drive or filesystem. try to compile from another directory.